# Getting Strapi to work with presigned URL

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi, image-upload

I am using fastAPI endpoint with code below :

```
    import logging
import boto3
import botocore
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
def create_presigned_url(bucket_name, object_name, expiration=600):
    # Choose AWS CLI profile, If not mentioned, it would take default
    boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='personal')
    # Generate a presigned URL for the S3 object
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name="ap-south-1",config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4',))
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.error(e)
        return "Error"
    # The response contains the presigned URL
    print(response)
    return response
```

also using S3 plugin for strapi to upload the images for blogs.
Strapi is unable to use this presigned url.
Any help is appreciated.